# tmux : config files are not used

Tags: config, tmux

I use tmux (tmux 1.8) from Ubuntu 14.04.
I wanted to configure it a bit via `~/.tmux.conf`. But whatever I set inside this file my tmux session looks the same. Then I tried a fresh new `/etc/tmux.conf` but I still get the same display.

It seems that my config is hardcoded and that I cannot change it.
If I remove these two files (`~/.tmux.conf` and `/etc/tmux.conf`) my tmux session is still the same. Tmux runs but I can not configure it. But it should be so simple...

Does anybody have already seen this? And how I could solve that? Do I need to compile a fresh new release of tmux?

**Today, I have more details :**

on one machine it works as expected. It's OK. But I did not changed anything! Strange...

But on another machine (also running Ubuntu same release and up2date like the first machine) it does not work.
The file /etc/tmux.conf does not exist on none of these 2 machines. I put this little config file (~/.tmux.conf) :

```
# start Window Numbering at 2
set -g base-index 2
```

When I launch tmux on this second machine, window numbering starts at 0. On the first machine with the same config file, it behaves correctly : it starts at 2.
I'm going crazy!

Comment: What do you mean by "the same"? What are you trying to change, and in what way? Show us the configuration.

Comment: after you changed your config file, have you tried starting new tmux session to check the difference? If you looked the existing session, it won't change, unless you reload the config in the session. (`source-file` command)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After you make changes to `~/.tmux.conf` make sure tmux sources them with the `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` shell command.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem. But I'm surprised that tmux doesn't read its config file by itself without using this line. Or there is another thing I don't see...

Comment: Tmux does not detect config file changes automatically.. that would be too much work. You either have to restart tmux server or source the changes manually with `tmux source-file` command.

Answer (score 7):

Try removing all sessions before running tmux. I have noticed that if you have sessions still running, tmux will still load the previous .tmux.config file.

Comment: I had to do this to get updates to .tmux.conf working with new changes (had several tmux sessions running, and new tmux sessions weren't reflecting changes).  `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` wasn't enough

Answer (score 2):

Executing `tmux kill-server` can stop the server and then try to run the server again using `tmux` command.

Please note that after killing the server you will lose all open sessions / tabs.